# Displaying newest post using partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models: posts, comments and questions. Comments belong to posts and questions belong to comments. I am getting an error when trying to show the last question belonging to a comment on the posts show page. Here is the error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the line giving the error which is located in the partial _comment.html.erb being called by the posts show page.

```
<%= comment.questions.last[:body] %>
```

I suspect the error has to do with the fact that it is being displayed on a posts page since

```
  <%= post.comments.last[:body] %>
```

does what i want.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if a comment has no questions then `comment.questions.last` would be `nil` and calling `[:last]` on it would raise the error. Try this

```
  comment.questions.last.try(:[],:body)
```

`try` method returns `nil` if the object calling it is nil else it evaluates the method passed to it on the object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added <%= render 'comment' %> to your Post show page?

Comment: Yeah, i'm rendering it with <%= render :partial => @post.comments %>